# Laravel 5.2 Getting Exception Undefined Variable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm working on Laravel and got stuck in this mess of `undefined variable $category`, I don't know why and where is the exact problem.

I have done this much.

AdminAjaxController

```
public function category()
{
    $category=DB::select('select category_name,category_id from categories');
    return view('admin.category_table',compact('category'));
}
```

category_table View

```
<table id="category" class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Category Name</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
            <th>Update</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
  @foreach($category as $value)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $value->category_id}}</td>
        <td>{{ $value->category_name}}</td>
        <th>Delete</td>
        <td>Update</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try this solution:

```
public function category()
{
    $category=DB::select('select category_name,category_id from categories');
    return view('admin.category_table')->with(['category' => $category]);
}
```

In addition to this you are getting this error, because you **do not send** your category variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
public function category()
{
    $category=DB::table('categories')->select('category_name', 'category_id')->get();

    return view('admin.category_table',compact('category'));
}
```

Comment: still the same thing.. :(

Comment: This have to work! please follow the steps `1. make sure the page is .blade.php 2. make sure you are in admin folder 3. run php artisan cache:clear 4. if still the problem give a screenshoot here`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will work.

```
public function category()
{
    $category=
      DB::select('select category_name,category_id from categories');
    return view('admin.category_table',[ 'category'=>$category ]);
}
```